# Keep an element at the centre of a div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web page that needs to be responsive.

Here is an image of it:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
        <div class="smallBoxes">
            <div class="leftHomeBox">

                <a class="Description" id="Desc_1">WHEN?</a>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.smallBoxes{
    display:block;
    margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:20%;
    width:auto;
}

.leftHomeBox{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:0;
    height:65px;
}


.Description{
    border:5px solid #ffffff;
    padding:5px;
}
```

I am trying to keep the "when" box in the centre of the div, for all screen sizes. AS things are now, both margins will change, but at different rates eg they do not stay consistent relative to each other and so the "when" box doe s not stay central.

I have looked at other websites and have not been able to find a working example.

I have tried using

```
margin-left:20%;
margin-right:20%;
width:auto;
```

but this does not work. I have been working on this all day and I have read all I can find but I cannot seem to get this to work. I have tried every possible thing I can think of.

Surely this is something that is required often and cannot be very difficult to achieve, but I am not able to find a clear answer to how to achieve this, or what I am doing wrong.

If someone could provide a fiddle of a working solution I would be very grateful.

Comment: Try putting text-align:center for .leftHomeBox.

Comment: position relative on the parent, position absolute on the child. left and top 50% then do a -50% transform (all on the child) (that's assuming you want the button vertically and horizontally centred.)

Comment: It's not clear why you have different margins of the parent block and I;m not sure why you are floating the first child but - http://jsfiddle.net/xuapj597/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

**CSS**

```
.leftHomeBox{
text-align:center
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ske75rp/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.Description
{
 display:block;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
```

This should be work.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a text-align: center on an `<a>` tag.

```
.leftHomeBox{
  text-align:center
}
```

It will center the link without using margins